# gulp не запускается в одной папке

Tags: node.js, gulp, консоль

Консоль выдает ошибку при запуске gulp в одной папке. В остальных папках работает. Кирилических символов в пути нет, npm reinstall & restart не помогло. В чем проблема может быть?

```
     events.js:183
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^
     Error
     at new JS_Parse_Error
     (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)
at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)
at croak (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2089:9)
at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2097:9)
at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2103:9)
at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2123:56)
at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2314:73)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2183:19)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2136:24)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (H:\...\realworld\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2904:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была при наличии в папке app/js файла popper.min.js
При удалении файла - ошибка пропадает. Такую же ошибку обнаружил с tilt.js